# Stack is always empty

Tags: c, stack

Even if when I am pushing something, the `keni(S)` always returns -1. Like I can push, but when I am trying to pop, it always returns "Stack is empty!". Thanks for your time!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

typedef struct{
    float s[N];
    int top;
}Stiva;

int keni(Stiva);
void dimiourgia(Stiva*);
void push(Stiva *, float);
float pop(Stiva *);

void dimiourgia(Stiva *St)
{
    St->top = -1;
}

int keni(Stiva S)
{
    if (S.top == -1)
        return -1;
    else 
        return 0;
}

void push(Stiva *St, float a)
{
    if (St->top == N-1) {
        printf("\n\nStack Overflow");
        return;
    }
    else {
        St->top ++;
        St->s[St->top] = a;
    }
}

float pop(Stiva *St)
{
    float c;

    c = St->s[St->top];
    St -> top--;

    return c;
}

int main()
{
    Stiva S;
    float x;
    int epil;

    dimiourgia(&S);
    do{
        do{
            printf("\n\n1.Push 2.Pop 3.End\n");
            scanf("%d", &epil);
        }while (epil<1 || epil>3);
        switch (epil) {
            case 1: if (S.top == N-1)
                        printf("\n\nStack is empty!\n\n");
                    else {
                        printf("\nPick a num\n\n");
                        scanf("%f", &x);
                        push(&S, x);
                    }
            case 2: if (keni(S) == -1)
                        printf("\n\nStack is empty!\n\n");
                    else {
                        x = pop(&S);
                        printf("\n\n==> %10.2f", x);
                    }
        }
    } while(epil!=3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger

Comment: @pm100 No problems have been detected.

Comment: @manolex What pm100 wondered (if I understand the question correctly) is, at what point didn't it "go your way"? At some point the result of some computation must be unexpected in order for you to get surprised by the final result.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh, to start with, at the 6th push, it should return stack overflow but nothing happens. Also even if I am pushing something (trying at least) when I am making the first pop, the stack is always empty

Comment: I have posted the answer but PLEASE, before writing anymore code learn to use your debugger. Set a breakpoint and single step, look at the content of the Stack struct as you go.

Comment: @manolex I know you are new here so I won't automatically downvote your question. Please put all relevant information in the question by editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anyway heres the fix

```
    switch (epil) {
        case 1: if (S.top == N-1)
                    printf("\n\nStack is empty!\n\n");
                else {
                    printf("\nPick a num\n\n");
                    scanf("%f", &x);
                    push(&S, x);
                }
                break; <<<<==============================
        case 2: if (keni(S) == -1)
                    printf("\n\nStack is empty!\n\n");
                else {
                    x = pop(&S);
                    printf("\n\n==> %10.2f", x);
                }
    }
```

at the moment after you push a number you immediately pop it again

```
1.Push 2.Pop 3.End
1

Pick a num

42


1.Push 2.Pop 3.End
1

Pick a num

44


1.Push 2.Pop 3.End
2


==>      44.00

1.Push 2.Pop 3.End
2


==>      42.00

1.Push 2.Pop 3.End
2


Stack is empty!



1.Push 2.Pop 3.End
```

Found by setting a break point where you call push and simply simgle stepping and watching the code